# Primefaces Component not updating using RequestContext

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I am trying to update a primefaces component after the 'isAdmin' value changes.

I am using the following HTML page:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabs">
        ...
        <p:tab title="Admin" rendered="#{userSession.isAdmin}">
        ...
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

My UserSession class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userSession")
@SessionScoped

public class UserSession {
    .
    .
    .
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public UserSession() {
         isAdmin = false;
    }

    public void addRole(String role) {
        if (role.equals("ADMIN") {
            this.isAdmin = true;
        }

        role.add(role)
    }
}
```

The addRole() method gets called and adds the role "ADMIN". I know this isn't a good way of doing things, but I'm only using it for testing purposes at the moment.

Then, under the class where I handle login and the addRole() method gets called, I am trying to update the component using:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form");
```

I have been trying to update the form as I believe this is always visible in the DOM?

My issue is, is that this is simply not working and nothing is being updated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was always actually changing my UserSession object instead of the actual session bean itself.

Therefore, I did the following and just pointed to my bean instead:

```
// Previously
// UserSession us = new UserSession();
UserSession us = (UserSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userSession");
```